# Multiple gradients and radial gradient with center outside of the element

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

Is it possible to get a similar result with CSS Gradients? Can you use 2 gradients on one div and can the radial one have a center outside the div?

[image: Desired result]

Comment: have a look at http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely possible to add more than one gradient to an element (even a combination of linear and radial gradients) by providing them in comma separated format like in the below snippet. The gradient that is specified first (from the right side) forms the bottom most layer while that which is specified last comes on top. Key thing to note is that the gradient (on top) must have colors with alpha less than 1 to be able to show the colors in the lower layers.

Coming to the second part of the question, radial gradients can be created such that their center point is outside the `div`. This can be done by specifying negative values for the [position](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#valdef-radial-gradient-position).

The gradient in the below snippet does not tally 100% with the image provided in question but you can get the idea.

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), radial-gradient(ellipse at -40% -50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 50%);
  background-size: 180% 200%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='gradient'></div>
```

Comment: Key thing to note is that the gradients must have colors with alpha less than 1 to be able to show the colors in the lower layers. Or set a background-size that limit the area covered by this gradient, and set repeat to false. (Just for completeness :-)

Comment: Very true @vals. I was referring more from a gradient stacking one on top of another perspective :)

Comment: This is pretty awesome! Well explained and very useful. I didn't find an example for this.

Comment: @SoBiT: Very glad that you found it useful :)

Comment: Another thing: Is it required that both gradients have alpha lower than 1? What is the render order of the gradients? Is it `background: front, to, back;` or `background: back, to, front;`?

Comment: @SoBiT: Sorry, I missed out the key part. They are read from the right, so the first value from the right is bottom. So it is `background: front, to, back`. And no, both gradients need not have alpha lower than 1, it is just the ones on top that need to have it.

Comment: Thank you. Worked pretty well now :)

Comment: If you would like to see how I realised it, have a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYgQNj

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
.color background: rgba(249,124,102,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249,124,102,1) 0%, rgba(246,160,147,1) 50%, rgba(248,85,63,1) 51%, rgba(243,93,73,1) 71%, rgba(236,98,85,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(249,124,102,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(246,160,147,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(248,85,63,1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(243,93,73,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(236,98,85,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249,124,102,1) 0%, rgba(246,160,147,1) 50%, rgba(248,85,63,1) 51%, rgba(243,93,73,1) 71%, rgba(236,98,85,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249,124,102,1) 0%, rgba(246,160,147,1) 50%, rgba(248,85,63,1) 51%, rgba(243,93,73,1) 71%, rgba(236,98,85,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(249,124,102,1) 0%, rgba(246,160,147,1) 50%, rgba(248,85,63,1) 51%, rgba(243,93,73,1) 71%, rgba(236,98,85,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(249,124,102,1) 0%, rgba(246,160,147,1) 50%, rgba(248,85,63,1) 51%, rgba(243,93,73,1) 71%, rgba(236,98,85,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f97c66', endColorstr='#ec6255', GradientType=1 );
}

    .rounded_rec {
     width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: black;
  }
```

Html

```
<div class="rounded_rec color">
</div>
```

Kindly check this [link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Check this [link](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28%5C-45deg%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28249%5C%2C124%5C%2C102%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C160%5C%2C147%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28248%5C%2C85%5C%2C63%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28243%5C%2C93%5C%2C73%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2071%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28236%5C%2C98%5C%2C85%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B') also

Check this [link](http://www.css3generator.in/css-gradient.html) and let me know is this what you want

Comment: Where is the radial gradient that OP is asking about?